# JAX-RS client and session management

Tags: jsf, authentication, jboss, client, jax-rs

My task is to split up an existing JSF Application into a JAX-RS web-service and a JSF web-client. The split should be done at the business layer. Both, client and server should run on a different JBoss AS7.1 Right now, both sides are using container managed authentication. The JSF-client only grants access to the uri-path /customers/* for users with role CUST and to /admin/* for users with role ADMIN. Of course the web-service protects his resources as well (Roles: CUST & AMDIN). Authentication for the web-service part is clear to me. So my question is how to I provide a proper authentication for the JSF-client. For me there are three possibilities:

1. Both sides manages their own authentication (Difficult to synchronize) **Is there a way to synchronize authenticated users between two JBoss application servers?**
2. Both sides manages their own authentication credentials and the, JSF-client sends with each request the `UsernamePasswordCredentials` to the web-service
3. Container-managed-authentication is only done at the web-service side. The JSF-client tries to request information, and in case of a response like: "peer not authenticated" the JSF-client forces the user to enter his credentials and performs the rquest again with `UsernamePasswordCredentials`

I really have no idea which (or whether) one of those three approaches is feasible. I have searched the web for a best practise approach, unfortunately without any success.

Is there any known best practice approach for this problem, or can you give me a hint for how do I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1. Yes, you can use [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) or [OpenID](http://openid.net/) with [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) for authorization

Ad 2. That's common approach in the "true REST" applications world - each call is stateless, everytime user credentials needs to be passed and checked.

Ad 3. If JSF application contains only data that can be accessible without authentication (JSFs are plain templates) that's reasonable solution.

Comment: Great answer, THX! OAuth seems to be the most proper solution. JBoss provides a nice documentation for [Authentication with OAuth](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/#d0e2687)